# Проблема с закрашиванием pictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: в обработчике события Click для button1 пишу следующее:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
 {
    pictureBox.BackColor = Color.Black; 
 }
```

Просто закрашиваю PictureBox чёрным цветом. Но он не закрашивается. Сделал MessageBox после закрашивания, выглядит это так:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{
   pictureBox.BackColor = Color.Black; 
   MessageBox.Show("Сообщение");
}
```

И так всё работает! Как думаете, почему так?

Comment: Если "всё работает" значит, что pictureBox закрашивается, то у меня есть версия, что так происходит из-за того, что окно не рендерится. Попробуйте вместо `MessageBox.Show("Сообщение");` написать `Refresh();`

Comment: Andrew, всё работает, спасибо.

Comment: Замечательно, оформил как ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что происходит в этой строчке выполняется, но не отрисовывается:

```
pictureBox.BackColor = Color.Black;
```

Эта строчка по каким-то причинам заставляет окно перерисоваться:

```
MessageBox.Show("Сообщение");
```

Так, что нужно выполнить перерисовку и всё заработает:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{
   pictureBox.BackColor = Color.Black; 
   Refresh();
}
```